# Calculate Weighted Scores Across Rows

Tags: r

I am seeking a more elegant way to calculate a weighted score of 7 columns as follows.

Each column represents a condition score (from 1 to 7), the observations represent the percentage observed at that score (each row must sum to 1).

The weighted score is simply the sum of each row variable multiplied by its condition score.

**Create a data set:**

```
rand.sum <- function(n) {
  x <- sort(runif(n-1))
  c(x,1) - c(0,x)
}

df <- t(replicate(10,rand.sum(7)))
colnames(df)<-c(1:7) # Change the column names to reflect condition value
df <- as.data.frame(df)
```

**Create the weighted score column (my way...):**

```
df$weightedCondScore <- ((df[,1]) * 1) + ((df[,2]) * 2) + 
                        ((df[,3]) * 3) + ((df[,4]) * 4) + 
                        ((df[,5]) * 5) + ((df[,6]) * 6) + 
                        ((df[,7]) * 7)
```

Is there a better way to calculate the weighted score by referencing the column names (scores) and a loop function? The data set contains a lot more columns and I don't really want to fix the index numbering in case it changes when additional variables are added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple way to get this is to treat it as multiplying a matrix times a vector.

```
M = as.matrix(df)
M %*% 1:ncol(M)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're someone who wants to build functions for quick tasks, you can use an `apply` family function to work across the columns weighting the values, then use `rowSums` to assign the score back to your data frame.

```r
weighted <- sapply(1:ncol(df), function(i) df[,i] * i)
df$weightedCondScore <- rowSums(weighted)
```

If you're one of those people like me who thinks in `tidyverse` pipes, one way that's more verbose, but still flexible, is to assign row numbers, work the data into a long shape, calculate the weighted scores by group, then reshape back to a wide format.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  gather(key = weight, value = value, -id) %>%
  mutate(weight = as.numeric(weight)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(wtd_score = sum(value * weight)) %>%
  spread(key = weight, value = value) %>%
  head(3)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 9
#> # Groups:   id [3]
#>      id wtd_score    `1`    `2`    `3`    `4`   `5`    `6`    `7`
#>   <int>     <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1     1      3.58 0.264  0.198  0.0508 0.0155 0.171 0.249  0.0508
#> 2     2      4.15 0.0640 0.0960 0.334  0.111  0.144 0.0295 0.221 
#> 3     3      5.24 0.116  0.0439 0.0548 0.102  0.148 0.0205 0.515
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>